# Как скопировать столбец из одной таблицы в другую таблицу и другой столбец в SQL Manager lite for PostgreSQL 6.2.0

Tags: postgresql, update, insert

День добрый , сразу говорю , совсем зеленый (студент) дали вот такое задание на подготовку к экзамену . Переместить из таблицы "Импорт" столбец "груз 2" в таблицу "BDData" столбец "cargo" , а потом в таблицу "BDData" столбец "cargo" добавить ещё столбец "продукт" из той же таблицы "Импорт". Работаю на SQL Manager lite for PostgreSQL 6.2.0 (Сборка 54471). Пробовал разные варианты , но так ничего и не вышло. Очень нужна помошь.

№1 в этом случае скомпилировалось , но результата нет.

```
INSERT INTO "BDData" (cargo)  SELECT "Импорт"."груз 2"
           FROM "Импорт";
```

№2 в этом случае Пишет "ОШИБКА: имя таблицы "Импорт" указано больше одного раза"

```
UPDATE BDData
SET ref_cargo = ref_"груз 2"
FROM "Импорт"
   JOIN "Импорт" ON 
      BDData.id = "Импорт".id AND BDData.a_ref1 = "Импорт".b_ref1
```

№3 тоже самое что и с №1 (скомпилировалось , но результата нет.)

```
UPDATE BDData t2 SET cargo = t1."груз 2"
   FROM "Импорт" t1
  WHERE t2.cargo::text = t1."груз 2"::text AND t2.cargo::text IS DISTINCT FROM t1."груз 2"::text;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение:

INSERT INTO "BDData" (cargo)
SELECT CONCAT("груз 2","продукт")
FROM "Импорт";